# ASPX.net login page, SQL connection- cannot open database error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, xampp, database-connection

new to aspx.net in visual studio.
So i'm trying to connect my Login.aspx to my database in Xampp so that the users in my userlist in the database can login,
but i have encountered this issue when i run my code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Cannot open database "attendance_system" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'CIAG-PC\CIAG'.
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider   StackTrace:

My code in Login.aspx:

```
System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["login"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        string query = "select count(*) from admin_user_list where LoginID ='"+txtUser.Text+"' and Password='" + txtpassword.Text + "' ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        if (output == "1")
        {
            // create session
            Session["user"] = txtUser.Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/User.aspx");
        }

        else
            Response.Write("Login Failed");
    }

}
```

And my Web.config for the connection:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Login" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=attendance_system;User ID=root; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I can't seemed to find any solutions that is connected to a different server instead of SQLEXPRESS server.i suspect the issue is in the connection strings code but i'm not sure what is wrong. Able to help?

Comment: What part of the error `Login failed for user` is unclear?

Comment: is your Sql 1.  Windows Authentication 2. Sql Server Authentication

Comment: My SQL is created in Xampp, so i'm not too sure about it. is there a way to check?

Comment: VDWWD, well i think it might be a dumb question to you but i really don't know what's wrong and i'm not sure if i'm answering your question correctly either.
i'm supposed to login from my login.aspx page with Username: admin and password: @dmin. These username and password are in the database called attendance system. the username and password for the database is the default ones right now so i did try to put "User ID= root" for my connection strings. so.. there shouldn't be any link to user 'CIAG-PC\CIAG'?

Comment: Not sure if conn string is case sensitive - `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["login"]`; `<add name="Login"`. also check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/.

Comment: @wazz oh, i didn't noticed that. thanks! Tried to changed them to lower case. Didn't work as well. I'll check the link out! Thanks!

Comment: i managed to make it try to connect to my database properly with the correct username and password. but now i still can't login. the error is stuck at con.Open(). my code in the webconfig is : add name="attendanceSystem" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;database=attendance_system" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />